# Suppose the 10% of apples in a supermarket are rotten. The manager checks the stock of apples, by inspecting them one at a time.

Tags: statistics

What is the probability that the 7th apple he inspects is the rotten one he finds? What distribution does the variable "number of inspected apples until the first rotten one" follow?

Comment: If there are an infinite number of apples and their rottenness are independent then you are looking at a geometric distribution

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean what are the odds that the 7th apple he inspects is the *first* rotten one?

If you have unlimited apples,

$$P(R=7) = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^6 * \frac{1}{10}$$
Which is around 0.05.

Check out a geometric distribution - defined as the distribution of the number of Bernoulli trials to get one success. Generally for the first rotten apple to be the kth apple:

$$P(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$$